# javascript: object is not a function

Tags: javascript

I write a module:

```
window.FileReader = (function () {

        var read = function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                console.log(e.target);
            };

            // reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };

        return {
            read: read
        };
    })();
```

but when I execute

```
FileReader.read()
```

it always warn me `object is not function` at `var reader = new FileReader()`

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/?redirect_from_locale=com There you have how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's saying that because you've made `FileReader` not a function, you've replaced it with an object (which has a function called `read`). All globals are properties of the global object (`window`, on browsers), so by setting `window.FileReader = { ... };`, you're replacing the global `FileReader` function with your object.

You seem to be trying to use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). That being the case, you want to **not** call your global module object `FileReader`, as that's defined by the File API. Call it something more specific to you (here I'm using `Foo` as an obviously-nonsense example):

```
window.Foo = (function () {

    var read = function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(e.target);
        };

        // reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

    return {
        read: read
    };
})();

// Usage:
Foo.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you code this line:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
```

make sure you define FileReader function in you code as below.

```
window.FileReader = function(){
    ...
};
```

In you code, you only return an object and assign it to window.FileReader, not a function, see you code as below：

```
window.FileReader = (function () { ... return {}; })();
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined FileReader as an object with a property read : `Object {read: function}`
you should first of all define FileReader as a constructor function like this:

> FileReader = function () {
>           var read = function (file) {
>               var reader = new FileReader();
>
> ```
>         reader.onload = function (e) {
>             console.log(e.target);
>         };
>
>         // reader.readAsDataURL(file);
>     };
>
>     return {
>         read: read
>     };
> };
> ```

And then you can create an object from this:

> var object = new FileReader();

Answer (score 0):

By the time `window.FileReader` been assigned, the function `read` was not been called, thus `var reader = new FileReader();` was not executed.

In fact, it is not executed until you call `FileReader.read()`. But at that time the value of `FileReader` inside the `read` function has already been replaced by your `window.FileReader`.

Moving `var reader = new FileReader();` out of the `function`, which makes it been executed earlier will eliminate the error:

```
window.FileReader = (function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    var read = function (file) {
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(e.target);
        };

        // reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

    return {
        read: read
    };
})();
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea having variables, especially global variables, named the same as something from the system APIs. So I'd prefer T.J. Crowder's way: just change the name of the global variable.